# Normal family with $\Im f(z)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I have to decide if this family is normal or not

$\mathscr{F}=\{f\in\mathscr{H}(D(0,1)): f(0)=2i\ \&\ \Im f(z)>0\ \forall z\in D(0,1)\}$

where $\Im f(z)$ is the imaginary part of $f(z)$.

I am trying to use Montel's theorem but I don't know how to decide if the family is bounded. I also tried to use a Möbius transformation but I didn't conclude anything. Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Use that $-i\mathscr{F}$ consists of functions $g$ with positive real part and fixed value $2$ at $0$ and the classical transformation $\frac{g-1}{1+g}$ that sends the $g$ family to the family of uniformly bounded functions (by $1$) on the disc; apply Montel to the last family (and also notice that you cannot have convergence to a constant $\pm 1$ there - corresponding to $0, \infty$ under the inverse Mobius, since the zero value under the transformation is $\frac{1}{3}$)